# Java Web Service Consumer > No client transport named 'null' found

Tags: java, web-services, lotus-domino, webservice-client

we are trying to develop Web Service Consumer in Lotus Notes in Java. 
We have used the automatic generated source code from Lotus Designer according to the wsdl file.

Calling methods from generated stubs in consumer from Local machine is working fine. But after setting an agent to run on Domino server this exception is screaming in log file:

```
02.06.2014 17:32:25   AMgr: Agent ('AttachmentDownloadServer' in 'test/AttachmentsDownload2.nsf') error message: No client transport named 'null' found!
02.06.2014 17:32:25   AMgr: Agent ('AttachmentDownloadServer' in 'test/AttachmentsDownload2.nsf') error message: at lotus.domino.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
02.06.2014 17:32:25   AMgr: Agent ('AttachmentDownloadServer' in 'test/AttachmentsDownload2.nsf') error message: at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Unknown Source)
02.06.2014 17:32:25   AMgr: Agent ('AttachmentDownloadServer' in 'test/AttachmentsDownload2.nsf') error message: at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
02.06.2014 17:32:25   AMgr: Agent ('AttachmentDownloadServer' in 'test/AttachmentsDownload2.nsf') error message: at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
02.06.2014 17:32:25   AMgr: Agent ('AttachmentDownloadServer' in 'test/AttachmentsDownload2.nsf') error message: at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
02.06.2014 17:32:25   AMgr: Agent ('AttachmentDownloadServer' in 'test/AttachmentsDownload2.nsf') error message: at lotus.domino.axis.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
02.06.2014 17:32:25   AMgr: Agent ('AttachmentDownloadServer' in 'test/AttachmentsDownload2.nsf') error message: at lotus.domino.websvc.client.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

We have already tried to append the library websvc.jar to the java library (we are not able to append it to the webservice consumer, because of the error: "The Script Libarary cannot be saved. The changes made to the generated source code would prevent its proper operation"). But it didnt help us.

We are developed it for the 8.5.3FP6 Domino Server in the 9.0.1FP1 Designer. We have tried to run this on 9.0.1 Domino Server as well, but with the same error.

Has anybody already seen this error? Any solution?

**Further details:**

I'm using the generated source code from Designer, where the `lotus.domino.websvc.client.*` classes used.

I thought that the Domino Server has access to that classes. The error is created in calling the invoke method in

```
lotus.domino.websvc.client.Call _call = createCall("xxx"); 
java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {pInputXml});
```

So the request isn't sent to Web Service Provider.

Comment: Are you using 3rd party engine? It would also help to see the SOAP request/response (where related) and WSDL.

Comment: No. Im using the generated source code from Designer, where are the lotus.domino.websvc.client.* classes used. I thought that the Domino Server has access to that classes. The error is created in calling the invoke method in lotus.domino.websvc.client.Call _call = createCall("xxx");
        java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {pInputXml});   So the request isnt sent to Web Servise Provider.

Comment: So your Java agent is calling to a Java Web Service Consumer library? Can you post the WSDL/SOAP messages. See: https://ibm.biz/BdRP9h

Comment: Yes, exactly. When i run this agent from Lotus Notes Client, the communication is working fine. The web service server of the 3rd party is responding. With SOAPUI is it working fine as well. The WSDL is here : http://dms.env.cz/T-WS/T-WS?WSDL, but i dont think it can help. The strange thing is that even on Domino server with the same version it is not working. I have tried now to create a new Consumer to other webService Provider wsdl, which is working for big project, and the error is the same.

Comment: So the same consumer generation engine with different wsdls, and the same problem. Maybe i could try to use Axis without domino extension. Or there is some inconsistency with java libs on Domino (or some setting).The other wsdl is here: https://eklep.odok.sysnet.cz/infobus/eklep-ws.nsf/eklepWS?wsdl. And again from local calling the agent, its working.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a problem with Runtime security level of the agent. Set it to "Allow restricted operations". Error listing is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at how you invoke it appears to are writing your own XML? Is this XML a SOAP message? Can you post a sample?

Is there a reason you are not using the default method.

For example after importing your WSDL I use this instead:

```
import lotus.domino.*;
import cz.env.dms.T_WS.T_WS_wsdl.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

      try {

          // Refer to cz.env.dms.T_WS.T_WS_wsdl.MZP_WS_TESTPortType.java for service interface methods:
         MZP_WS_TESTPortType stub = new MZP_WS_TESTLocator().getMZP_WS_TESTPort();

         // Setting endpoint to test mockservice in SoapUI.
         //stub.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8088/mockservice");
         stub.setEndpoint("http://dms.env.cz/T-WS/T-WS");

         String answer = stub.getMyVersion();

         System.out.println(answer);

      } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the *target end point* for the call and it worked for me:

```
call.setTargetEndpointAddress(TARGET_ENDPOINT);
```